# Controlling multiple servo motors on rpi 4

Tags: gpio, pi-4, power, servo

Do I need a hat module for my raspberry pi to control 6 servos? I’ll be using an external power source.

Answer (score 0):

No.

All you need for servos is a correct control signal.  Normally this is a 50 Hz pulse between 1 and 2 milliseconds long.  It needs to be accurate and repeatable within a few microseconds.

You can use a PCA9685 chip to generate the pulses.  You can find such modules quite inexpensively.

Alternatively you can use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) which can generate the needed pulses.

pigpio is preinstalled with some Raspbian installations (not Raspbian Lite).  If not preinstalled it can normally be installed with

`sudo apt install pigpio`